# What is the difference between Cloud IAP and Cloud Endpoints OAuth?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth

With regards to authentication and authorization, what does Cloud IAP do that Cloud Endpoints doesn't? (and vice versa?)

Is Cloud IAP doing both Authorization and Authentication? And if so, is it using OAuth to do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Cloud IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/) is an access management tool that allows people to use their internal business apps without requiring to connect to a VPN. It is based on the context such as the IP address of the client or type of the request.
As per the architectural concept of Cloud IAP it does perform '[Authenticaion](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview#authentication)' and '[Authorization](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview#authorization)' . When you turn on Cloud IAP for a resource, it automatically creates an OAuth 2.0 client ID and secret. If you delete the automatically generated OAuth 2.0 credentials, Cloud IAP won't function correctly.

[Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) on the other hand is simply used to manage your APIs by basically allowing developers to generate their own keys. It uses Auth0 and Firebase authentication. To get more understanding about Cloud Endpoints, you could also review its ['Architecture'](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/architecture-overview#cloud_endpoints_architecture) as well.